# Manually create jar for use with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to create a `jar` file including some files from a non-java project and then have Maven be aware of the file, so I can define dependencies on it and so on.

Is there a way to "mavenize" an existing `jar`, or create a "maven jar" from some files, so that I can easily (in script) define its `artifactId, versionId` and other information?

Comment: Yes. refer https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: `deploy:deploy-file` is more what I need. Is it also somehow possible to define dependencies on other jars like this? edit - or just tell maven to generate the pom file for me and I could then manually add the dependency declaration?